# Strapi custom logger configuration

Tags: strapi

I have got a Strapi v4 app with the following:

**./config/logger.js**

```
'use strict';

const {
  winston,
  formats: { prettyPrint, levelFilter },
} = require('@strapi/logger');

module.exports = {
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'debug',
      format: winston.format.combine(
        levelFilter('debug'),
        prettyPrint({ timestamps: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS' })
      ),
    }),
  ],
};
```

and additionally in my **./config/functions/bootstrap.js** i have got the following code

```
 'use strict';

/**
 * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
 * your application gets started.
 *
 * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
 * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
 */

module.exports = () => {

    console.log("Hello World!");
    logger.log("debug","Hello Strapi app!");

};
```

Unfortunately i do not see it anywhere printed in my folder Strapi app or Web browser. Any idea that could help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the logger inside the middleware config file, see https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations/middlewares#logger

Comment: Your link actually literally says to create a dedicated configuration in `./config/logger.js` and that is exactly what OP is doing. Your answer may be valid for v3 but not v4.